# Why do I measure 0 V between the negative pole of a battery and the ground?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, voltage, capacitance, batteries

I today confused the entire company (we work on batteries for trains) when I stumbeled about the following fact:

When you touch the negative pole of a battery having electromagnetically isolated shoes, without touching its other end, nothing happens to you.

I thought: No.

The battery has an surplus of (negatively charged) electrons. These electrons will flood into my body creating a measurable electric current until a charge balance is created (charging of a plate capacitator). Seemingly, they do not. Why?

I then continued after my work to do the following expirement:

I took a battery out of my computer mouse. I measured the voltage between its ends (one end at the time) and the ground. 0 Volt. I also measured the current. 0 Ampere. My assumption was the battery would push the electrons through the cable into the ground. It does not. Why? Why would I need isolated shoes in the first place?

I wonder if this is true for all capacities, especially plate capacitors.

EDIT: In production we use Voltages up to 3kV.The battery I used for the grounding test only has 1.5V

Comment: Could you _edit your question_ with the voltage of your company's traction batteries?

Comment: Thanks, I did it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_capacitance): "The Human Body Model for capacitance, as defined by the Electrostatic Discharge Association (ESDA) is a 100pF capacitor in series with a 1.5kΩ resistor."

From [Desco Industries](https://desco.blog/2012/07/30/electrostatic-discharge-esd-person-can-feel/): "Most people do not start feeling the effect of an ESD event until the discharge is at least 2000 volts. It typically takes a ESD discharge of greater than 2,000 or 3,000 volts for a person to feel the 'zap'."

If you are isolated from ground and touch a conductor (such as your battery terminal), current will flow for about half a microsecond (three time constants of that 1500 ohms and 100pF).  Technically this is measurable, even with a 1.5V battery -- but it would be a very difficult measurement to make.

Two conditions would have to be met for you to feel a zap from your traction batteries: first, there would need to be a potential *difference*.  Over time things inside that railcar will end up having potentials close to the car's frame.  If the battery is grounded to the car via its negative terminal, then when you touch it, you'd already be close to its potential.  Even if you touched a terminal that was a few hundred volts different, you *probably* wouldn't feel anything (see the comment from the Desco site).

So, all in all -- yes, a current will flow.  However, if you're truly isolated from ground then you won't notice it unless your batteries run to thousands of volts -- in which case you're violating all sorts of safety precautions by playing with them.

Comment: The battery ends don't have an _absolute_ voltage (relative to ground) of 1.5V unless the negative terminal is shorted to ground. They have a voltage between the anode and the cathode of 1.5V. The absolute voltage of either end 
(and your own absolute voltage before touching it) is completely uncertain, and can fluctuate wildly if it is, for example, charged up by having been rubbed against something shortly after being electrically isolated from the ground. Your answer has some valuable considerations, but I think you missed some as well.

Comment: I was trying to answer the question _as asked_ -- "why don't I notice this voltage".  I tried to stick with that.  Yes, if it's a dry day and you scuff your feet on the carpet walking up to a 1.5V battery, you're going to notice some electricity, but it's going to be (A) way more than 1.5V, (B) unrelated to the battery, and (C) unrelated to the question.

Comment: I guess my point is - undefined voltages relative to ground _do_ have everything to do with the question. In my mind, the battery doesn't shock you for the same reason touching a stone sitting on some rubber doesn't shock you. Unless you complete the circuit the fact that it's a battery, and the 1.5V figure, is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer! The other question might remain; Why do I measure 0V to the ground with a normal 1.5 V Battery, when I do not close the circuit.

Comment: @Niclas because your voltmeter has a finite resistance. Any voltage difference between the battery terminal and ground discharges through the meter. That only requires moving a *tiny* amount of charge, and by the time it's been connected long enough to make a measurement, the voltage *is* zero to within the meter's resolution.

Comment: But if I would take lightbulb (or an led) and connect it between the ground and the battery it would not light, right (even for a small time period)? The battery would not get discharge over time?

Comment: Yes, but that's a different question than what I understood your first question to be.  Continuous DC current cannot flow without a conductive path.

Comment: I think it is much more nuanced than that.
If the battery would have a net negative amount of charge on its negative terminal and I connect this to the ground (given ground has an net 0 amount of charge), there would be flow as long as not all charges are equalized. The lightbulb will light.
However this is not the case.
I am afraid it hat something todo with the topology of a perfect capacity, which has no field outside of itself:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Parallel-plate_capacitor

Comment: @Niclas in the case of an incandescent bulb, the total amount of energy required to equalize the voltage is so small that although a current does briefly flow, it's not enough to get the filament warm, let alone glowing hot. In the case of an LED there might be a very brief, very dim flash of light, but probably too small to notice. And once you bring that terminal to the same potential as ground, it will pretty much stay there until you do something to change it, so you can't just do the trick over and over.